# Linq to Sql Count Include joins

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a Linq to sql as following:

```
var members=db.Members.Include(x=> x.Contact).Count();
```

Now due to some bad data all contacts in my members don't have corresponding Contact record. So during the count how can i include the Count after Inner Join with the Contact table.

The problem is when i get the list of members, the list of members has **100 Records** while Count has **150 records (50 records being bad data)**.

```
var membersQ=db.Members.Include(x=> x.Contact).Select(i=> new MemberViewModel(){
 Name = i.Contact.Name,
 ContactId= i.Contact.Id,
 CreatedDate= i.CreatedDate
}).AsQueryable();
var members=memberQ.ToList();// =100,paging is done...
// the memebers list uses paging but the count doesn't
var total=membersQ.Count(); // =150
```

I checked the Resulting Query during count, apparently it doesn't do `JOIN` with Contact table while `Count()`

**Update**
Database structure

```
Member Table
Id   ContactId, CompanyId, CreatedDate ...

Contact Table
Id   Name ...
```

The foreign key for ContactId in Member table is not set in database level but on the Model only.

```
[ForeignKey("ContactId")]
Public Contact Contact { get; set; }
```

The bad data goes like this

I had previously 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 as Contact records and all those contacts were in Member table too.

Now I deleted records from Contact table lets say 6-10. But happened not to delete from Member table.

So this is causing an issue with the count. Yah sure, deleting the bad data from Member solves the issue but the question is how to use `join while using Count()`.

Note: I use database initializer null

**Update 2**
I used LinqPad and Tried both default `Linq To SQL` and `EntityFramework` (DbContext) connection and what i found is confusing.

For Query:

```
(from a in Members
join b in Contacts on a.ContactId equals b.ContactId
select a).Count()
```

Using Default Linq To SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [Member] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Contact] AS [t1] ON [t0].[ContactID] = [t1].[ContactID]
```

Using Entityframework DbContext

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Member] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

In my code i use the DbContext method. So.. don't know what to do here
.
btw: Sorry for having a tag with `linq-to-sql` it is actually `entityframework`

Comment: just for fun. try. memberQ.Contacts.Count() (that should be 100)

Comment: So I will have to use different Query that select `Contact`, than the one used for `ToList`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```
var x = from m in Members 
        join c in Contacts on  m.ContactId equals c.ID
        select new 
        {
            Name = c.Name,
            ContactId= c.ID,
            CreatedDate= c.CreatedDate
        };

Console.Write(x.Count());
```

**EDIT**

When I use LinqPad with this query and look at generated SQL I get:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [Members] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Contact] AS [t1] ON [t0].[ContactId] = ([t1].[ID])
```

**EDIT 2**

You could also try this:

```
var x = from c in Contacts
        from m in Members where m.ContactId == c.ID
        select new 
        {
            Name = c.Name,
            ContactId= c.ID,
            CreatedDate= c.CreatedDate
        };

Console.Write(x.Count());
```

Comment: Actually this also doesn't work, the resulting query doesn't do join with `Contact`

Comment: @Ruchan when I use LinqPAd and run the query I get an Inner Join: SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value] FROM [Members] AS [t0] INNER JOIN [Contact] AS [t1] ON [t0].[ContactId] = ([t1].[ID])

Comment: @Ruchan added another method, let me know how you get on

Comment: it still returns the same query i mentioned for DbContext method.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is right but, are the records containing bad data, duplicates? If yes, then why not use distinct() to only get those 100 good records? If all you want is just the count from the list, then why not use:

```
var members = memberQ.ToList();
int total = members.Count;
```

Comment: For the sake of example i used ToList directly, but i need to do paging in the records. The count is not required to have paging.

Answer (score 2):

**The answer to this** is simply you have no connection between Members and Contact. The Members table has 150 rows and the Contact table has 100 rows. So when you try to fetch you actually pair the data row by row until some table is finished. When you count you count the first table.

**Solution** You need to add a FK to Contacts from Members or any type of identifier you can "bind" the data to on Members from Contact.

**More explanation & even more in comments**

In the table `Members` you have a reference to a `Contact`. which you populate with your `Include(x=> x.Contact)` statement

So when you try to make this

```
new MemberViewModel(){
    Name = i.Contact.Name,
    ContactId= i.Contact.Id,
    CreatedDate= i.CreatedDate
}
```

You are asking for content of a Contact (as you probably know.)

Now for some explanation. When you query the database as you do into the `MembersQ` you are not fetching/realizing the data. (you are just preparing a query)

To realize a query you must call `ToArray()`, `ToList()` etc. And when you do a `foreach` on the data you realize one row at a time (cursor).

Now for your result, when you call ToList() you are realizing the list of type List (now only elements able to fill are used (this is your 100))

When you are performing `memberQ.Count()` you ask for a count of the query from the database, as the database knows nothing about the `MemberViewModel` it will return the counts of Members matching a possible `Where(x=>{filter})` (this is your 150)

A simple fix is to write `ToList()` instead of `AsQueryable()`. Im alittle rusty on LINQ-to-SQL you might have to do `AsQueryable().ToList()`

A possible solution is to filter beforehand.

```
var membersQ=db.Members.Include(x=> x.Contact).Where(a=> a.Contact != null).Select(i=> new MemberViewModel(){
    Name = i.Contact.Name,
    ContactId= i.Contact.Id,
    CreatedDate= i.CreatedDate
}).AsQueryable();
```

now `membersQ.Count()` should be equal to var `membersQ.ToList().Count()`

And to perform paging use `memberQ.Skip(x).Take(y)` this will be performed on the SQL and not on the webserver. Unless you `ToList()` then everything is on server as its suddenly a set of data in server memory.

**If that dont work**, then you dont have a foreigh key present, you could just change the filter to filter in ContactID instead of Contact. of add a FK (Foreign Key)

**Add foreign Key:** If you have access to modify your SQL then make the ContactID in Members nullable and add a foreign key to from the members ContactID and Contact's ID.

Then delete the two tables from your dbml and drag them in again from the db explorer. Now you should be able to simply use the code without includes as is will be "Lazy loaded" (meaning no includes) versus Eager loaded (meaning you have to say what to load)

Comment: Yeah, the `ToList `does solve the problem, but creates another problem. **Too much data** The `ToList` will list all the records from the database, which when used paging doesn't require. Yeah i have not put an example of paging, but i have cited in the post that there will be paging. The count is the Total count of Records in database without paging.

Comment: Added a example at the bottom, see if that dont help

Comment: I have used the `a.Contact != null` and it still doesn't work. The resulting query doesn't have join or check for existing `Contact` on `Count()`

Comment: Ohh. hmm that looks to mean that you don't actually have a Foreign Key present.

Comment: another thing, make the `Where` on the `a.ContactID != null` instead of `a.Contact != null` since you dont have access to the Contact object in the query yet. (added more stuff to the end of the answer.

Comment: But you have a huge issue in your database records if the join from @Steven Ford did not work. what row in Contact matches row 1, 2 or 3 in Members? does Members have anything relating to a row in Contact? for an example the ID in contact should relate to something in Member. If not then you are just saying that row 1 in member and row 1 in Contact relates, same for 2 and 2, 3 and 3 etc. (this you absolutely should not, as the order of the rows must be assumed to be read randomly from SQL)

Comment: i have updated the question, see if it helps. and rather than `a.ContactID != null`, `a.Contact.Name != null` solves it and uses Inner Join.

Comment: Are you sure you are using linq-to-sql? the more i analyze the more is wrong in your approach. `a.ContactID` is the correct place to check first (same table) and then possibly `a.Contact.Name` (other table) only helkps if name is nullable aswell as ContactID

Comment: `a.ContactID` is never null. The foreign entity of the reference (ie: Contact) can be null. Are you talking about `a.Contact.Id`? I am using entityframework 6.1 which uses Linq to SQL

Comment: LINQ to SQL is its own thing (Big difference, EF is not the same, Now LINQ is used but it is not equal to LINQ to SQL). If `a.ContactID` is never null then you of course must filter on what defines the data as dirty (like name). If FK like `a.ContactID` is non nullable in the database then the `a.Contact` is also never null (if you do it in the logic layer, then you are asking for problems, and EF should say then the model is out of sync). But this is a problem that would solve itself if you added the foreign key in the SQL/DB layer where it belong.

Comment: Seem the Default linq to SQL does the inner join but the DbContext from entityframework doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var members=db.Members.Include(x=> x.Contact)
                      .Where(x => x.Contact != null)
                      .Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var members = db.Contracts.Where(w=> w.Member != null).Select(i=> new MemberViewModel(){
 Name = i.Contact.Name,
 ContactId= i.Contact.Id,
 CreatedDate= i.CreatedDate
}).AsQueryable());
```

Is this somewhat what you're after?